# Can Von Neumann (fourier) stability analysis be used for $v_t=Bv_{xx}$ with homogeneous dirichlet boundary conditions?

Tags: numerical-methods

My book says that Von Neumann analysis can be used when boundary conditions are periodic, in other words it says when $v(0,t)=v(1,t)$.

I am confused if pdes with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions can be analyzed with the fourier analysis or whether one must use another method... It seems like the boundary conditions meet the condition $v(0,t)=v(1,t)=0$, but I don't know if it is really considered periodic or not...

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, it is spatially periodic.

Comment: Thank you Chee Han. I appreciate your time. :)